# Setup SVN with Wamp

Tags: svn, wamp

I would like to make a website with other people. For this purpose, I believe that a SVN repository with WampServer is the best solution, isn't it ?

But I have a problem for installing it. I've followed this tutorial : http://www.reloadedpc.com/other/setup-wamp-svn-subversion-windows/

Before I add lines :

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Everything works (WAMP icon is green). But after, WAMP icon is orange. Could you help me please ? I've already tried to restart my computer.

Wamp : 2.2
SVN : 1.6.6

My log :

```
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win64) PHP/5.3.13 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 19:41:17
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5084
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Child process is running
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Jan 30 21:20:26 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:19 2013] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:19 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:20 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Released the start mutex
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:21 2013] [notice] Child 5084: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:21 2013] [notice] Child 5084: Child process is exiting
[Wed Jan 30 21:21:21 2013] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

If what I get you're saying is that after you add those LoadModule lines it doesn't work for you, the most likely problem is that you either have a faulty module or you're missing one. Check the error log and you should find out what is happening:

```
c:\wamp\logs\apache_error.log
```

Comment: Looks like something else is wrong. Can you be more detailed in your steps? Are you restarting WAMP after you add those lines? Are you sure that those modules exist in the modules directory?

Comment: WAMP icon is green. I close WAMP. I add those four lines. (yes, the modules exist in the modules directory) I start WAMP. WAMP icon is orange. When I add only the two first lines, WAMP works.

Comment: If it's bombing on those last 2 lines something is wrong with either your svn modules or your svn install. I'd try re-installing svn using the tutorial on the tortoise svn site: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-apache.html

Comment: The link http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100, given in http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-apache.html, is not correct. So I've re-installed SVN by another way, but it still doesn't work. But it's possible that the mistake comes from here. Have you another link for installing SVN please ?

Comment: If you're reinstalled svn, make sure you update those modules. That's most likely what's causing your problem. I don't use windows so you'll have to google other installs of svn for windows.

Comment: Yes, I've updated those modules. So, I'll continue to search.

Comment: I've downloaded SVN here : http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/?source=dlp and there is no longer libdb44.dll, but libdb48.dll. Is it possible that the tutorial http://www.reloadedpc.com/other/setup-wamp-svn-subversion-windows/ is no longer relevant ? I've not founded a more recent tutorial...

Comment: Yeah that tutorial is from 2-3 years ago so if you want to use the latest you'll want to find something much more recent

Answer (score 0):

Well, recommended config (in `LoadModule` part) is

```
LoadModule dav_module         modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

- `dav_module`, not `dav=_module`
- nobody tells about `dav_fs_module`

Comment: Sorry, the = was a mistake here only. I've deleted the second line, but it still doesn't work...